# Using connectors after find command

Tags: command-line, find

I want my bash to print 'found' only if something is found, using the find command. But using && does not help: even if found nothing, I'm getting 'found' printed.
Example:

```
$ pwd
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/test/test1/test4
$ ls
xaa  xab
$ find . -name xac && echo 'found'
found
$ find . -name xaa && echo 'found'
./xaa
found
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make `find` itself print `found`:

```
find . -name xac -printf "found\n" -quit
```

The `-quit` will make `find` [quit after the first match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62883/70524), so `found` is only printed at most once.

On a similar thread on Unix & Linux ([make find fail when nothing was found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198254/70524)), I used `grep -qz` to return a non-zero exit status if `find` found nothing:

```
find /some/path -print0 -quit | grep -qz .
```

Which you can use to construct compound commands using `&&` or `if`:

```
find /some/path -print0 -quit | grep -qz . && echo found
```

Comment: I had to stare at this awhile.  `/some/path` tells find where to start looking, but nothing tells it what to look for. Same in your linked answer. What does work for me is `find /some/path -name xac -print0 -quit | grep -qz . && echo found` . Did I miss something?

Comment: @Joe what matters here is the `-print0 -quit`. What you put before that depends on what you want to find. I chose to omit that here.

Answer (score 13):

[muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971162/295286) is appropriate and well suited for cases where we want to print something if file is found. For general case when we want to execute external command, such as `echo`, we could use `-exec` flag.

```
$ find . -name 'xac' -exec echo "I found " {} \; -quit             
I found  ./xac
```

The `{}` part passes filename to the command between `-exec` and `\;` as arguments. Note the `\` before `;` - it prevents shell from misinterpreting it； in shell closing semicolon signifies end of command, but when escaped with slash , shell will treat it as literall text to be passed to `find` command and to find command it serves as closing `-exec` flag's arguments.

---

For constructing conditionals of the `if found do this; else do that` sort, we could make use of command substition `$()` and `test` command ( aka `[` ):

```
$ [ "x$(find . -name 'noexist' -print -quit)" != "x" ] && echo "found" || echo "not found"                                                                                              
not found

$ [ "x$(find . -name 'xac' -print -quit)" != "x" ] && echo "found" || echo "not found"                                                                                                  
found
```

---

**Addressing Dan's comment**

Dan in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971159/using-connectors-after-find-command/971165?noredirect=1#comment1556695_971165) asked:

> Wouldn't echo "I found {}" be better than echo "I found " {}? Maybe for echo it's fine, but if someone copies the command and replaces echo with another command, they may have a problem

Let's understand the problem first. Usually, in shells there's concept of word-splitting, which means unquoted variables and positional parameters will be expanded and treated as separate items. For instance, if you have variable `var` and it contains `hello world` text, when you do `touch $var` the shell will break it down into two separate items `hello` and `world` and `touch` will understand that as if you were trying to create 2 separate files; if  you do `touch "$var"`, then shell will treat `hello world` as one unit, and `touch` will create one file only. This is important to understand that this happens only due to how shells work.

By contrast, `find` doesn't suffer from such behavior, because commands are processed by `find` itself and executed by `execvp()` system call, so there's no shell involved. While curly braces do have special meaning in shells, because they appear in the middle of `find` command, and not in the beginning, they carry no special meaning to shell in this case.  Here's an example. Let's create a few difficult filenames and try to pass them as argument to `stat` command.

```
$ touch with$'\t'tab.txt with$' 'space.txt with$'\n'newline.txt

$ find -type f -exec stat -c "%F" {} \; -print                                                                                                                         
regular empty file
./with?newline.txt
regular empty file
./with space.txt
regular empty file
./with?tab.txt
```

As you can see, `stat` receives difficult filenames perfectly fine with `find`, which is one of the main reasons why it is recommended for usage in portable scripts, and especially useful when you're traversing directory tree and want to do something with filenames that might potentially have special characters in them. Therefore, it is not necessary to quote curly braces for commands executed in `find`.

It is a different story when shell gets involved. Sometimes you need to use a shell to process filename. In that case, quoting will indeed matter, but it's important to realize that it's not find's problem - it is the shell that does word splitting.

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c "stat {}" sh \;   
stat: cannot stat './with': No such file or directory
sh: line 1: newline.txt: command not found
stat: cannot stat './with': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat 'space.txt': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat './with': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat 'tab.txt': No such file or directory
```

So when we quote *within shell*, it will work. But again, that's important for shell, not `find`.

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c "stat -c '%F' '{}'" sh \;                                                                                                                 
regular empty file
regular empty file
regular empty file
```

Comment: Wouldn't `echo "I found {}"` be better than `echo "I found " {}`? Maybe for echo it's fine, but if someone copies the command and replaces echo with another command, they may have a problem.

Comment: @Dan the topic was too long to discuss in the comments, so I made an edit to my answer. Please see it

Comment: Thanks for finally getting me to understand why that semicolon needed to be there. Also, great explanation of quoting.

Comment: Wasn't expecting so many details as a reply to my comment. I very much appreciate that explanation, thanks!